# SQL Cross table/Pivot table for orders and products

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an 'Orders' table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
[OrderID]      INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DatePurchase] DATETIME NOT NULL,
[Quantity]     INT      NOT NULL,
[TotalPrice]   REAL     NOT NULL,
[ProductID]    INT      NOT NULL,
[MemberID]     INT      NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrderID] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([ProductID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ProductID]),
FOREIGN KEY ([MemberID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([MemberID])
);
```

I want to create a pivot table query that is able to show the the amount of orders for each product that uses the products names as the column headers (which is Product.Name from the Product table).

Example data:

```
Orders table:
OrderID    Date                 Quantity   TotalPrice     ProductID  MemberID
1          22/11/2017 00:00:00  3          39             14         27

Products table: 
ProductID   Price     Name 
11          13        Shorts
```

Example output:

```
      Shorts    Top     Trousers
Orders    2         3       1
```

I have tried looking around but just can't get my head around these types of queries, can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you use a reporting tool?  they typically have crosstab functions like you're looking for.
Are your product names well defined, so they're always known and they never change?

Comment: The product names aren't well defined, that's why I use the ProductID as the primary key.

Comment: You're better off doing this work in the reporting layer, then.